# vim function "update timestamp" on event "BufWrite" : to be improved

Tags: linux, unix, vim, file-io

The use case is shared by all (vim) developers around the world (IMHO) : we would like to update a *tag* and a *timestamp* on each write operations in the sources files. My attempt with the help of Barry Arthur is this :

### Example of string to update on each writes

```
# 2013-01-09 01:04:31.0 +0100 / Me <me@domain.tld>
```

### The vimrc code

```
" if not maped, :x don't call UpdateTimestamp()
map :x :wq
function! UpdateTimestamp()
  let old_pos = getpos('.')
  let old_search = histget("search", -1)
  g/^\(#\|\/\/\)\s\+\d\{4\}-\d\{2\}-\d\{2\}\s\+\d\{2\}:\d\{2\}:\d\{2\}\.\d\+\s\++\d\{4\}\s\+\/\s\+Me <me@domain.tld>.*/s/.*/\="# " . strftime('%F %H:%M:%S.0 %z') . " \/ Me <me@domain.tld>"/
  exe "normal /".old_search
  call setpos('.', old_pos)
endfunction

au BufWrite * call UpdateTimestamp()
```

### problems not solved

- the undo history should not be modified when updating the tag (if possible)
- the position of the screen change on writes
- there's some not wanted errors displayed on the screen when the pattern is not found

### question

Simple : how to solve these issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need saving/restoring position at all, neither using `setpos()` nor `winrestview()`: you can just not move the cursor. Neither you need tricks to save/restore search: use `search()` function in place of `:g` and `setline()` in place of `s/.*/\=`:

```
function! UpdateTimestamp()
  " Removed “.*” from the end of the pattern because it is pointless
  " Also made it use very-magic mode because otherwise it looks bad (too many escapes)
  " Also replaced \d\{2\} with \d\d because \d\d takes less characters
  let lnr=search('\v^(\#|\/\/)\s+\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d\s+\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\.\d+\s+\+\d{4}\s+\/\s+\VMe <me@domain.tld>', 'wn')
  if lnr
    " Matchstr gets comment leader. Above regex intended to work with # or // comments, but \=expression supported only the former, this got fixed
    call setline(lnr, matchstr(getline(lnr), '^\S\+')." " . strftime('%F %H:%M:%S.0 %z') . " / Me <me@domain.tld>")
  endif
endfunction
```

. Note: there is still one difference between your and mine solution: here only one timestamp is updated. This issue can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

- RE: the history should not be modified when updating the tag 
  You mean undo history, right? That's against Vim's design. Every change needs to be represented. Best you can do is `:undojoin`, but I would find this confusing.
- RE: the position of the screen change on writes 
  You need to use `winsaveview()` / `winrestview()` instead of just `setpos()`.
- RE: there's some not wanted errors displayed on the screen when the pattern is not found 
  Pass the `/e` flag at the end of `:substitute`, and prepend `:silent!` to `:global`.

PS: I think there are plugins on vim.org that do what you want. Have you tried some of them?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, no I have not seen these, but I will search.

Comment: I still have "E486: Motif introuvable" (pattern not found error) with the `/e` modifier at the end of the `//s///e` regex.

Comment: Ah sorry, you also need `:silent! g/...`

Comment: You can also make use of the `try ... catch ... finally ... endtry` construct in Vim to handle errors.

Comment: @Daan: Yes, but here we want to _ignore_ errors. That would mean wrapping each command in its own try..catch to avoid that the remaining commands aren't aborted.